# How did Nucky rise to power?

Tags: plot-explanation, boardwalk-empire

How did Nucky Thompson wrest power over Atlantic City from The Commodore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the Boardwalk Empire wiki](http://boardwalkempire.wikia.com/wiki/Nucky_Thompson):

> Nucky was the Atlantic County Sheriff from 1908 to 1912. During this
>   period he married Mabel Thompson. In 1912, the Atlantic City
>   organization was the target of a campaign of depuration led by the
>   then Democratic Governor of New Jersey Woodrow Wilson; Nucky and The
>   Commodore made a deal under which The Commodore would take the fall
>   and go to jail for a number of years, while Nucky would succeed him as
>   County Treasurer and take control of the organization, ensuring that
>   things continued the same and The Commodore still received a share of
>   the profits.

This information seems to originate from the episode [Belle Femme](http://boardwalkempire.wikia.com/wiki/Belle_Femme_recap) (season one, episode nine):

> The Commodore reminds Nucky that he spent five years in prison
>   following his time in the throne. Nucky counters that he knew that one
>   of them had to go. The Commodore shakes his head and says that he had
>   no choice. Nucky asserts that he also had none and that was the reason
>   they made their deal, he asks if they can drop the subject.

Which is explained in depth in the episode [A Return to Normalcy](http://boardwalkempire.wikia.com/wiki/A_Return_to_Normalcy_recap) (season one, episode twelve):

> The Commodore says that Jimmy should not talk to him about justice. He
>   recalls his own prosecution at the hands of Woodrow Wilson, then an
>   ambitious State Governor looking to run for President. Jimmy asserts
>   that Wilson is the reason The Commodore went to jail. The Commodore
>   counters that Nucky was responsible, explaining that they made a deal
>   with the prosecutor that one of them would go to prison on the
>   election rigging charges so that Wilson would get his headlines and
>   the other could keep running things. Jimmy wonders why it was The
>   Commodore and not Nucky who took the fall. The Commodore explains that
>   Nucky was an untarnished "golden boy" figure in local politics at the
>   time so it made sense. The Commodore confides his resentment for what
>   he perceives as Nucky for forgetting about him during the five years
>   he was in prison.